# Echoing database value in checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm sure this has been asked a million times before but I can't find a clear answer anywhere. I'm using [Bootstrap Switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/). The switch is updating the database just fine but I want the switch to be in the OFF postion if $live='0' and in the ON position if $live = '1'. At the moment it just stays in the ON position regardless of what $live is.
I just cant figure it out, I'd really appreciate any help.

The html

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="live" checked data-on-color="warning"  <?php if($live=='1'){echo 'CHECKED' ;} ?>>
```

And the php extract:

```
if( isset( $_POST['live']) )
    {
        $live = '1';
    } else {
$live = '0';
}
```

And the final piece of abbreviated php:

```
 $sql = ("UPDATE members SET `live` = '$live' WHERE `username` = '$username'");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have set your value to 1 (always) and I see checked on your html above

Try this!

```
<input type="checkbox" 
    value="<?php echo (isset($live))?$live:'1';  ?>" 
    name="live" data-on-color="warning"  
    <?php echo (isset($live) && $live == '1' )? 'checked="checked"':''; ?>
>
```